# how to log query execution time for oracle with java application?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am trying to log query execution times for my application which is based on Eclipse link JPA and oracle DB.

I've enabled tracing for my application which uses ojdbc6_g.jar as detailed here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm. It works well and does all the logging but i didn't see the query execution time anywhere.

As we are using Eclipse link JPA and tried to use the performance profiler but looks like it is supported in the latest versions whereas we are on 1.x and cannot upgrade now since we are closer to a release. Ours is a standalone Java application.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: i don't know any _java_ solutions but oracle offer several ways tracing a session. of you can turn on oracle trace using `dbms_Session` for the session, you can query `v$sql` or `v$active_Session_history` for older queries.

Comment: If you know your function name that does the JDBC operation, you can use https://github.com/alfredxiao/jackplay to trace your function. It gives you the input and output and time elapsed in your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the above responses. I found JProfiler to be very useful in regards to displaying query execution times and other details. Except that its not free and also i am trying to look for something that will work the same way as logging does in the long run.

-Sree

Answer (score 0):

**log4jdbc** is a Java JDBC driver that can log SQL and/or JDBC calls (and optionally SQL timing information) for other JDBC drivers. The `jdbc.sqltiming` logger provided by the project will allow you to record the execution of the SQL statements executed.

Follow it here:

https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

In my case a while ago to get **query execution times**, 
`execTime = timeBeforeJPA - timeAfterJPA`

or you can use @Juned suggestion